# Create a nested comma-separated-list from a CSV file

Tags: lists, external-files, csv, comma-separated-list

In my Latex document I define a nested list that looks like this:

```
\def\recipes{
{
test1@
test2@
test3@
test4@
test5a*test5b@
test6a*test6b
},
{
test1@
test2@
test3@
test4@
test5a*test5b@
test6a*test6b
}%
}
```

Instead of defining this list in the Latex document, I'd like to parse these data from a CSV file. I looked into various libraries, but so far, I only could find examples that make tables out of a CSV file or I couldn't understand the example. Isn't there an easy and obvious way to transform a CSV file like this in the above mentioned list?

```
test1,test2,test3,test4,test5a*test5b,test6a*test6b
test1,test2,test3,test4,test5a*test5b,test6a*test6b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation using `expl3`. I endeavored to make the resulting macro exactly the same as the one you build manually, although there are several spaces that are probably unwanted.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
test1,test2,test3,test4,test5a*test5b,test6a*test6b
test1,test2,test3,test4,test5a*test5b,test6a*test6b
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makelistfromcsv}{mm}
 {% #1 = control sequence, #2 = file name
  \scm_listcsv_make:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\ior_new:N \g_scm_listcsv_input_ior
\clist_new:N \l__scm_listcsv_temp_in_clist
\clist_new:N \l__scm_listcsv_temp_out_clist
\tl_new:N \l__scm_listcsv_temp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \scm_listcsv_make:nn
 {
  % clear the "out" clist
  \clist_clear:N \l__scm_listcsv_temp_out_clist
  % open the input csv file
  \ior_open:Nn \g_scm_listcsv_input_ior { #2 }
  % read one line at a time
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_scm_listcsv_input_ior
   {
    % store the current line as a clist
    \clist_set:Nn \l__scm_listcsv_temp_in_clist { ##1 }
    % store the items to the temporary tl adding "@ space"
    \tl_set:Nx \l__scm_listcsv_temp_tl { {{ ~ \clist_use:Nn \l__scm_listcsv_temp_in_clist { @~ } ~ }} }
    % add the tokens as an item of the "out" clist
    \clist_put_right:NV \l__scm_listcsv_temp_out_clist \l__scm_listcsv_temp_tl
   }
  % now build the final token list
  \tl_new:N #1
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { ~ \clist_use:Nn \l__scm_listcsv_temp_out_clist { , ~ } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\recipes{
{
test1@
test2@
test3@
test4@
test5a*test5b@
test6a*test6b
},
{
test1@
test2@
test3@
test4@
test5a*test5b@
test6a*test6b
}%
}

\makelistfromcsv{\newrecipes}{\jobname.csv}

\ifx\recipes\newrecipes % are they equal?
  \typeout{EQUAL :-D}
\else
  \typeout{UNEQUAL :-(}
\fi
```

The output is

```
EQUAL :-D
```

The `filecontents*` environment is used just for making the example self-contained and you can use any file on your system.

A “spurious-space-free” version:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
test1,test2,test3,test4,test5a*test5b,test6a*test6b
test1,test2,test3,test4,test5a*test5b,test6a*test6b
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makelistfromcsv}{mm}
 {% #1 = control sequence, #2 = file name
  \scm_listcsv_make:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\ior_new:N \g_scm_listcsv_input_ior
\clist_new:N \l__scm_listcsv_temp_in_clist
\clist_new:N \l__scm_listcsv_temp_out_clist
\tl_new:N \l__scm_listcsv_temp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \scm_listcsv_make:nn
 {
  % clear the "out" clist
  \clist_clear:N \l__scm_listcsv_temp_out_clist
  % open the input csv file
  \ior_open:Nn \g_scm_listcsv_input_ior { #2 }
  % read one line at a time
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_scm_listcsv_input_ior
   {
    % store the current line as a clist
    \clist_set:Nn \l__scm_listcsv_temp_in_clist { ##1 }
    % store the items to the temporary tl adding "@"
    \tl_set:Nx \l__scm_listcsv_temp_tl { {{\clist_use:Nn \l__scm_listcsv_temp_in_clist { @ } }} }
    % add the tokens as an item of the "out" clist
    \clist_put_right:NV \l__scm_listcsv_temp_out_clist \l__scm_listcsv_temp_tl
   }
  % now build the final token list
  \tl_new:N #1
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \clist_use:Nn \l__scm_listcsv_temp_out_clist { , } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\recipes{%
{%
test1@%
test2@%
test3@%
test4@%
test5a*test5b@%
test6a*test6b%
},%
{%
test1@%
test2@%
test3@%
test4@%
test5a*test5b@%
test6a*test6b%
}%
}

\makelistfromcsv{\newrecipes}{\jobname.csv}
\ifx\recipes\newrecipes % are they equal?
  \typeout{EQUAL :-D}
\else
  \typeout{UNEQUAL :-(}
\fi
```

With this code, the replacement text of `\newrecipes` is

```
{test1@test2@test3@test4@test5a*test5b@test6a*test6b},{test1@test2@test3@test4@test5a*test5b@test6a*test6b}
```

without spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! That's exactly how I imagined it.